# ROS Answers SE migration: AMCL freeze

Tags: localization, navigation, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm using the AMCL node to localize my robot, I launch the AMCL and localized the robot whitin rviz (using default configuration *rosrun amcl amcl scan:=laser*), I see the particle cloud and all seem to work fine, then when i start to move the robot the particles freeze out. The AMCL node don't report any issue but still it doesn't publish anything.

I was trying different configurations and i realize that if i set the maximun particle number up to 500 the node work fine and it doesn't freeze out, for any particle cloud larger than that the AMCL stop working

Any advice?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12367/amcl-freeze/) by [jrcapriles](https://answers.ros.org/users/269/jrcapriles/) on ROS Answers with karma: 370 on 2011-12-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I already found the answer to my question. There is a bug with amcl node about uniform particle distribution that was fixed and integrated to navigation stack on version diamondback 2.4.6, my robot has ROS diamondback version 2.4.5 running on it so I use the amcl node for 2.4.6 version and it works fine

https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5115

---

Originally posted by [jrcapriles](https://answers.ros.org/users/269/jrcapriles/) with karma: 370 on 2011-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2